# Check mime type of file on upload with PHP. mime_content_type, fileINfo, linux file NOT available

Tags: php, linux, mime-types

i have been scouring the web all day and am unable to find a reasonable solution to this problem.

i am trying to help a client hobble back together a site that was moved from another host to godaddy shared hosting.

the site is built using CakePHP and one line uses mime_content_type, which is not available on this server. neither is the FILE command and neither is fileinfo.

i tried the upgrade.php replacement, but it fails presumably because it can't find mime_magic.

the PEAR solution fails due to FILE not being available.

is there any solution to this?

the only goal here is to find out whether or not a file is a PDF or not, not based on the extension.

PHP Version 5.2.17

thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDF files always start with `%PDF-`, so you can read the first 4 bytes and check that they're equal to that.

```
function is_pdf($fn) {
  $f = fopen($fn, 'rb');
  if ($f === false) return false;
  $res = fread($f, 5) == '%PDF-';
  fclose($f);
  return $res;
}
```

However, it may be easier just to [download](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/file/file-23/file/magic/magic.mime?txt) the MIME magic file, and give its name to [`finfo_open`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-open.php) (php 5.3+) or configure [`mime_magic.magicfile`](http://php.net/manual/en/mime-magic.configuration.php#ini.mime-magic.magicfile) and use `mime_content_type`.

Comment: finfo_open is not available pre 5.3. but reading the file is a good idea.

Comment: @Jason Oops, forgot you're on an old php version. If possible, update to 5.3 - its new [features](http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.new-features.php), not to speak of the new functions, are long overdue. Anyway, you can also configure `mime_magic.magicfile` in php.ini. Updated the answer with that.

Comment: this is good enough. what i did was simply upload mime-magic to the same dir as the mime.php from upgrade.php package and change the mime-magic paths in mime.php and voila. thanks!