# How to ensure the MIME type of a file is of any image format in PHP Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, mime-types

I am trying to ensure only image types are uploaded to the server, however, there seems to be confusion using `mine_content_type` when trying to accept `HEIC` formats (live photos from IOS). The following formats found on Google: `image/heic` and `image/heif` are not working.

```
if (in_array(mime_content_type($file->getRealPath()), ['image/jpeg', 'image/gif', 'image/png', 'image/bmp', 'image/svg+xml', 'image/heic', 'image/heif']))
    # Good File
else
    # Bad File
```

Does anyone know of a better way to ensure the file is only of type `image/*`? At first I thought about exploding the `mime_content_type($file->getRealPath())` at the `/` and ensuring that the first segment was always `image` but this seems like re-inventing the wheel and probably less secure and there must be a better way to do it.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Full Code:

```
foreach ($request->allFiles() as $key => $files)
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if (in_array(mime_content_type($file->getRealPath()), ['image/jpeg', 'image/gif', 'image/png', 'image/bmp', 'image/svg+xml', 'image/heic', 'image/heif']))
            # send to CDN server
            $response->attach('photos[' . Str::random(20) . ']', file_get_contents($file->getRealPath()), Str::random(20) . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension());
        else
            # Currently the only "quick-fix" for unsupported image types
            return back()->withErrors(['One or more files was not supported by our CDN platform. Try turning off Live Photos.']);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With `mime_content_type` you can use the `mime_magic.magicfile` to set a mime file in `php.ini`

With [File Information](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php) the function [finfo_open](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-open.php) can open a mime magic file with the file information

In Linux you can build your own [mime.magic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7236191/how-to-create-a-custom-magic-file-database) file, Apple has his own [mime magic](https://opensource.apple.com/source/file/file-23/file/magic/magic.mime.auto.html) file but heic/heif files are missing

If don't want to mess with configurations you can check the first bytes of the `image/heic` and `image/heif` files and create a class/function to detect those specific file types, e.g. for PDF the first 4 bytes are: `%PDF-`

```
function is_pdf($fn) {
  $f = fopen($fn, 'rb');
  if ($f === false) return false;
  $res = fread($f, 5) == '%PDF-';
  fclose($f);
  return $res;
}
```

^[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7668168/453348)